# Full-Screen apps black after sleep/hibernate windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, intel-core-i7, nvidia-rtx

I just built a new computer with a 2080 Super on an i7.

Everything works great, but full-screen apps like overwatch will go to black screens after the computer has been in sleep or hibernate. If I just turned the computer on, the apps work fine.

Once the computer goes to sleep once, opening these apps goes to a black screen, but with sound. However, as soon as I open my windows menu and the bottom bar comes to front, the full-screen application shows itself in the back. As soon as I click back into the full-screen app, it goes black again.

I have tried setting these applications to window or borderless windowed, and still no avail. All drivers are up to date as I built this computer a few days ago. Searching around on the internet has pulled up a bunch of power options that I have played with, but none helped. I have also tried setting the computer to hibernate instead of sleep, but the issue still occurs.

Comment: I would suspect a GPU driver issue. Could you try your system with a different grapics card?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have another graphics card handy. Tried different settings in power management, and bios to no avail :/